# How can I reduce memory-use on this combinatorics computation?

Tags: matlab, memory-management

I have the following program:

```
m = 4;
N = 3;

a = [ones(N+m-1,1)' zeros(m,1)']; % creates an array with specified number of 0's and 1's
b = perms(a);
c = unique(b,'rows'); % with these last two lines, I find all possible combinations

% the rest is probably not relevant for the question

d = [ones(length(c),1) c ones(length(c),1)]; 

a_powers = zeros(length(d(:,1)),1);
for i = 1:length(d(:,1))         
    a_powers(i) = nnz(diff(d(i,:))==0);
end

[n_terms,which_power]=hist(a_powers',unique(a_powers'));
```

But my computer runs out of memory when I try m=5 and N=2, with the following error:

```
  Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

  Error in perms>permsr (line 53)
  P = V(P);

  Error in perms (line 26)
  P = permsr(V);
```

I thought I could use nchoosek() or combnk(), but they didn't do what I wanted (to get all possible *different* combinations of a given number of ones and zeros in an array).

What can I do to optimize my program?

Thanks!

Comment: `perms`  blows up in size rather quickly with lengthy arrays, hence the warning you shouldn't use it with more than 10 elements in an array. The optimisation way is to buy more RAM than fits in a proper sky scraper.

Comment: @Adriaan Hehe, yeah, that's one solution, although I was hoping I could use something like nchoosek() or combnk() (or something similar) to obtain all possible different combinations of the array elements, instead of first finding all permutations and then deleting all rows that are equal.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do... are you just trying to get all bit strings with a specific number of bits set? That should be exactly what `nchoosek` does.

Comment: @beaker Given an array with N+m-1 ones and m zeros, I want a matrix in which all possible combinations of the ones and zeros are listed as rows. For example, if I have [1 1 1 0], I want [ 1 1 1 0; 1 1 0 1; 1 0 1 1; 0 1 1 1]. It shouldn't matter in which order the ones and the zeros are in the initial array. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nchoosek` is what you're looking for. For each row in the result, `nchoosek` will give the column numbers of the ones. The remaining columns of that row will be zero.

```
m = 4;
N = 3;

numberOnes = N+m-1;   % This is `k`
patternLength = numberOnes + m;   % This is `n`
patternCount = nchoosek(patternLength, numberOnes);   % Total number of combinations
bitPatterns = zeros(patternCount, patternLength);     % Preallocate output matrix

patterns = nchoosek(1:patternLength, numberOnes);     % Gives us the column numbers of the 1's
bitLocations = bsxfun(@(r,c) sub2ind(size(bitPatterns), r, c),   % Convert the column numbers in to array indices
                                [1:patternCount]', patterns);    %   for each row in `patterns`
bitPatterns(bitLocations) = 1;   % Set all of the bitLocations indices to 1
```